# How to get a file name from a file's byte array?

Tags: java, arrays, apache, file, apache-commons

I have the bytes representing a file that I am transmitting over a network. Besides reconstructing the file manually on the file system, how can I get the information from the File, such as getName(), getPath(), etc?

In other words:

1. I start out with a File on machine A
2. I use FileUtils to turn the file into a byte array
3. I transmit that file over a network to machine B
4. On machine B, I want to reconstruct that byte[] into a File and run methods such as getName()

The following does not work

1. (File) bytes --> Does not convert
2. ((File) ((Object) bytes))) --> Does not convert either

I would really rather not create a new temporary file on the filesytem, although I know there are static File.createTemp available that will do that. I'd prefer to just keep it in memory, construct a new File object from the byte[] array, get the information I Need and be done.

Actually, what would be even better is an API that will take the byte[] and from it, directly get the file name by parsing the bits.

Comment: Does FileUtils output data about the file and/or the file's contents?

Comment: FileUtils will dump the byte[] into an actual File, on the File System itself. But, I just want to access the File from memory. I.e., just grab the .getName() contents. See FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, data);

Comment: You have to send the name/path/etc. across the network along with the bytes.

Comment: @Kevin isn't the file name information stored in the byte[] though?

Comment: No. The byte[] has the contents of the file, no more, no less. Well, maybe less if there's a problem reading. It's no different from any other byte[].

Comment: My mistake then. For some reason I thought the file name was there. Appreciate the clarification everyone, I will program a workaround :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `byte[]` that is returned by `FileUtils.readFileToByteArray` is only the file contents, nothing else.

You should create your own class that is Serializable that includes two fields: a `byte[]` for the file contents, and a `java.io.File` that has everything else you need.  You then serialize/deserialize your class into `byte[]`, which is transmitted.

Answer (score 1):

The file contents and its name are two separate and independent things. While a specific file format could have metadata to store the name in the contents (similar to e.g. ID3 tags for MP3), in a typical file there is no way to know the name from `byte [] contents`. Also even if, it would be the name from a remote machine which may be invalid on the target platform.

If you want the name you need to transfer it separately.

Answer (score 0):

As others have correctly stated, FileUtils is giving you the contents of the file.

You want to transfer file meta-data (filename/pathname, create/modify/access time, ownership, permissions, size, and (probably) a checksum) in addition to the contents of the file.  One way you could do this is to place the file into a container (tar, shar, zip, etc), which provides the file meta-data as well as the file contents.  Or you could use a file transfer protocol which transfers this meta-data.

Answer (score 0):

you can as well invent your own protocol for sending information with file Bytes
Mine as follow

**`file Name` then separator then `file Path` then separator then `file bytes`**

**`separator`** should be character that can't be used as fileName for file Path (i.e |, :, & ...)

**`deassemble`** at receiving client deassemble bytes in a reverse order and extract information sent.