# How to download image or pdf stored as LONGBLOB in database in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

In the project's requirements the user should be able to upload image or pdf and later can download it.

For now I know how to do it if the type of the file is known, for example if it's a Pdf :

```
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getSupportDoc(@PathVariable String code) throws Exception {

  byte[] file = myService.findDocByCode(code).getFile();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    headers.setContentLength(file.length);


    return new ResponseEntity<>(file, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

this works perfectly, and if the file is image I need just to change the line:

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
```

to:

```
headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
```

My question is how to detect automatically the type and set the MediaType ?
I have read this answer :

[How to get a file name from a file's byte array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912267/how-to-get-a-file-name-from-a-files-byte-array)

but I'm wondering if there's any easier way to do it

Comment: I have a similar endpoint. Im returning ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> instead of byte[], and contentType is set to MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM. You can try those maybe.

Comment: @dauthDaert06 I created a ByteArrayResource : `ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(file);`
and returned `return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);`
when I test it I download empty file ( o octet) without any extension

Comment: Hmm.. are you in control of the database ? When client uploads a file, you are the one who inserts the file to the database and can you change the table (add a column) ?

Comment: Yes, are you thinking of adding new column to store the file type ? or changing the data type of the file to VARCHAR (encode the file to base64) ?

Comment: well, by using ByteArrayResource the downloaded file is not empty but it doesn't have extension.

Comment: Yes I was thinking of adding fileName column if that solves your problem. MultipartFile has a method getOriginalFilename() which returns the fullname (like 'image.png'). And when serving you can add this name in the header.
`FileEntity fileEntity = myService.findDocByCode(code);
return ResponseEntity.ok()
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
                    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + fileEntity .getFileName() + "\"")
                    .body(new ByteArrayResource(fileEntity .getFile()));`

Comment: @dauthDaert06 I didn't want to add more columns but it seems to be my only solution, I'll do it.
 Next time I'll use base64 instead of this. Thank you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254464/discussion-between-hamzadevxx-and-dauthdaert06).